# parse json in swift 5 I got no data

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json file in swift. Its body looks like that and I still receive no data!
Can any one tell me how the structs should looks like? What am i missing?

This is the received json:

```
{
    "blocked_list": {
        "total": 2,
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 49,
                "name": "fdewer12faasd",
                "profilePicture": "",
                "followStatus": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the json parsing code:

```
func parseJSON(_ blockdata: Data) -> CurrentUserBlockListModel? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CurrentUserBlockList.self, from: blockdata)
        let usersArray = decodedData.users
        let count = decodedData.total
        let blockModel = CurrentUserBlockListModel(users: usersArray,total:count)
        return blockModel
        
    } catch {
        print("error ")
        return nil
    }
}
```

These are my structs:

```swift
struct CurrentUserBlockList : Codable  {
    let total : Int?
    let users : [users]
}

struct users : Codable {
    let followStatus : Int?
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let profilePicture : String?
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code you used for parsing

Comment: The issue is on the second line, fifth character. More seriously: What's your code?

Comment: here is the code : 

    func parseJSON(_ blockdata: Data) -> CurrentUserBlockListModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CurrentUserBlockList.self, from: blockdata)
            let usersArray = decodedData.users
            let count = decodedData.total
            let blockModel = CurrentUserBlockListModel(users: usersArray,total:count)
            return blockModel
            
        } catch {
            
            print("error ")
            
            return nil
        }
    }

Comment: What the declaration of `CurrentUserBlockList`, of `CurrentUserBlockListModel`? `print("error ")` Is that called? Anyway, please print `print("error: \(error) ")`, print the error thrown that would have interesting values.

Comment: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "total", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"total\", intValue: nil) (\"total\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Add important information to the question by editing it instead of posting it as comments, it will make it easier to read and the question will become clearer for everyone. But the error implies that `total` is not defined in the right place, maybe you can sort that out yourself.

Comment: The top level key in your json is "blocked_list" but you have not included this level in your struct hierarchy.

Comment: how can I implement it ?

Comment: A top level struct that has that property that is of type CurrentUserBlockList or decode as a dictionary `decoder.decode([String: CurrentUserBlockList].self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are trying to decode is wrongly defined.

If use your `Parsing Code`, make new Struct

```swift
struct SolutionObject: Codable {
  let blocked_list: CurrentUserBlockList
}

struct CurrentUserBlockList : Codable  {
    let total : Int?
    let users : [users]
}

struct users : Codable {
    let followStatus : Int?
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let profilePicture : String?
}
```

And change your `parsing Code`

`CurrentUserBlockList` --> `SolutionObject`

```swift
func parseJSON(_ blockdata: Data) -> CurrentUserBlockListModel? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(SolutionObject.self, from: blockdata)
        let usersArray: [users] = decodedData.blocked_list.users
        
        let count: Int? = decodedData.blocked_list.total
        guard let count = count else {
          return nil
        }       

        let blockModel = CurrentUserBlockListModel(users: usersArray, total: count)
        return blockModel
    } catch {
        print("error")
        return nil
    }
}
```

**JSON is basically made of key and value pairs.**

and

**Use the Optional Carefully.**